# Change "Preprint" to be as "To be submitted" at the end of first page in elsarticle template

Tags: titles, elsarticle

I'm writing a paper which prepare to submit to Elsevier journal using `elsarticle` template, when I compile the latex, a line of *Preprint submitted to... * come out at the end of the first page. I found a way to remove this line, but I'm wondering is that possible to change them as *To be submit to ...* ? If we can change them, how to do these?

Answer (score 2):

You can update the macro responsible for printing it by manually updating it, or patch it using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint]{elsarticle}

\title{A title}
\author{An author}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ps@pprintTitle}% <cmd>
  {Preprint submitted}% <search>
  {To be submitted}% <replace>
  {}{}% <succes><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```